# Spark Dataframe ORDER BY giving mixed combination(asc + desc)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe that I want to sort column by descending if the count value is greater than 10.

But I'm getting a mixed combination like ascending for couple of records then again descending and then again ascending and son on.
I'm using `orderBy()` function which sort the record in ascending by default.

Since i'm new to Scala and Spark I'm not getting the reason for why I'm getting this.

```
df.groupBy("Value").count().filter("count>5.0").orderBy("Value").show(1000);
```

reading the csv

`````
val df = sparkSession
    .read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv("src/main/resources/test.csv")
    .toDF("Country_Code", "Country","Data_Source","Data_File","Category","Metric","Time","Data_Cut1","Option1_Dummy","Option1_Visible","Value")````
`````

the records I'm getting by executing the above syntax:

```
+-------+-----+
|  Value|count|
+-------+-----+
|      0|  225|
|   0.01|   12|
|   0.02|   13|
|   0.03|   12|
|   0.04|   15|
|   0.05|    9|
|   0.06|   11|
|   0.07|    9|
|   0.08|    6|
|   0.09|   10|
|    0.1|   66|
|   0.11|   12|
|   0.12|    9|
|   0.13|   12|
|   0.14|    8|
|   0.15|   10|
|   0.16|   14|
|   0.17|   11|
|   0.18|   14|
|   0.19|   21|
|    0.2|   78|
|   0.21|   16|
|   0.22|   15|
|   0.23|   13|
|   0.24|    7|
|    0.3|   85|
|   0.31|    7|
|   0.34|    8|
|    0.4|   71|
|    0.5|  103|
|    0.6|  102|
|   0.61|    6|
|   0.62|    9|
|   0.69|    7|
|    0.7|   98|
|   0.72|    6|
|   0.74|    8|
|   0.78|    7|
|    0.8|   71|
|   0.81|   10|
|   0.82|    9|
|   0.83|    8|
|   0.84|    6|
|   0.86|    8|
|   0.87|   10|
|   0.88|   12|
|    0.9|   95|
|   0.91|    9|
|   0.93|    6|
|   0.94|    6|
|   0.95|    8|
|   0.98|    8|
|   0.99|    6|
|      1|  254|
|   1.08|    8|
|    1.1|   80|
|   1.11|    6|
|   1.15|    9|
|   1.17|    7|
|   1.18|    6|
|   1.19|    9|
|    1.2|   94|
|   1.25|    7|
|    1.3|   91|
|   1.32|    8|
|    1.4|  215|
|   1.45|    7|
|    1.5|  320|
|   1.56|    6|
|    1.6|  280|
|   1.64|    6|
|   1.66|   10|
|    1.7|  310|
|   1.72|    7|
|   1.74|    6|
|    1.8|  253|
|    1.9|  117|
|     10|   78|
|   10.1|   45|
|   10.2|   49|
|   10.3|   30|
|   10.4|   40|
|   10.5|   38|
|   10.6|   52|
|   10.7|   35|
|   10.8|   39|
|   10.9|   42|
|  10.96|    7|------------mark
|    100|  200|
|  101.3|    7|
|  101.8|    8|
|    102|    6|
|  102.2|    6|
|  102.7|    8|
|  103.2|    6|--------------here
|     11|   93|
|   11.1|   32|
|   11.2|   38|
|  11.21|    6|
|   11.3|   42|
|   11.4|   32|
|   11.5|   34|
|   11.6|   38|
|  11.69|    6|
|   11.7|   42|
|   11.8|   25|
|  11.86|    6|
|   11.9|   39|
|  11.96|    9|
|     12|  108|
|  12.07|    7|
|   12.1|   31|
|  12.11|    6|
|   12.2|   34|
|   12.3|   28|
|  12.39|    6|
|   12.4|   32|
|   12.5|   31|
|  12.54|    7|
|  12.57|    6|
|   12.6|   18|
|   12.7|   33|
|   12.8|   20|
|   12.9|   21|
|     13|   85|
|   13.1|   25|
|   13.2|   19|
|   13.3|   30|
|  13.34|    6|
|   13.4|   32|
|   13.5|   16|
|   13.6|   15|
|   13.7|   31|
|   13.8|    8|
|  13.83|    7|
|  13.89|    7|
|     14|   46|
|   14.1|   10|
|   14.3|   10|
|   14.4|    7|
|   14.5|   15|
|   14.7|    6|
|   14.9|   11|
|     15|   52|
|   15.2|    6|
|   15.3|    9|
|   15.4|   12|
|   15.5|   21|
|   15.6|   11|
|   15.7|   14|
|   15.8|   18|
|   15.9|   18|
|     16|   44|
|   16.1|   30|
|   16.2|   26|
|   16.3|   29|
|   16.4|   26|
|   16.5|   32|
|   16.6|   42|
|   16.7|   44|
|  16.72|    6|
|   16.8|   40|
|   16.9|   54|
|     17|   58|
|   17.1|   48|
|   17.2|   51|
|   17.3|   47|
|   17.4|   57|
|   17.5|   51|
|   17.6|   51|
|   17.7|   46|
|   17.8|   33|
|   17.9|   38|---------again
|1732.04|    6|
|     18|   49|
|   18.1|   21|
|   18.2|   23|
|   18.3|   29|
|   18.4|   22|
|   18.5|   22|
|   18.6|   17|
|   18.7|   13|
|   18.8|   13|
|   18.9|   19|
|     19|   36|
|   19.1|   15|
|   19.2|   13|
|   19.3|   12|
|   19.4|   15|
|   19.5|   15|
|   19.6|   15|
|   19.7|   15|
|   19.8|   14|
|   19.9|    9|
|      2|  198|------------see after 19 again 2 came
|   2.04|    7|
|   2.09|    8|
|    2.1|   47|
|   2.16|    6|
|   2.17|    8|
|    2.2|   55|
|   2.24|    6|
|   2.26|    7|
|   2.27|    6|
|   2.29|    8|
|    2.3|   53|
|    2.4|   33|
|    2.5|   36|
|   2.54|    6|
|   2.59|    6|
```

Can you tell me what is wrong i'm doing.
My dataframe has column

```
"Country_Code", "Country","Data_Source","Data_File","Category","Metric","Time","Data_Cut1","Option1_Dummy","Option1_Visible","Value"
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of your input dataframe? Value column should be a Double or a numeric type, but it seems to be a String or something according to the behaviour you are showing to us

Comment: it's a csv file i'm reading it like this. see I have edited how I'm reading this

Comment: Before the order by perform a printSchema and you'll see the schema which is inferring. I think you'll see Value is a String instead of a numeric value, so it's ordering it lexycographically instead of numerically

Comment: ok then how can i restrict the datatype while reading a csv file

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked about in the comments, it seems your Value column is of type String. You can cast it to Double (for instance) to order it numerically.

This lines will cast the Value column to doubleType:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

df.withColumn("Value", $"Value".cast(DoubleType))
```

**EXAMPLE INPUT**

```
df.show
+-----+-------+
|Value|another|
+-----+-------+
| 10.0|      b|
|    2|      a|
+-----+-------+
```

**With Value as Strings**

```
df.orderBy($"Value").show
+-----+-------+
|Value|another|
+-----+-------+
| 10.0|      b|
|    2|      a|
+-----+-------+
```

**Casting Value as Double**

```
df.withColumn("Value", $"Value".cast(DoubleType)).orderBy($"Value").show
+-----+-------+
|Value|another|
+-----+-------+
|  2.0|      a|
| 10.0|      b|
+-----+-------+
```

Comment: yes man you are right It was a String previously I just ````printSchema()```` and checked thanks man for your answer